# For Loops in Assembly - (Clarification)

Tags: assembly, for-loop

This is just a clip of the file. THis is one of the levels in a bomb. each level is defused by an input by the user. We're supposed to interpret the disassembled code to figure out what that input should be. In this specific level the user has to input 5 numbers. Once the 5 numbers are provided they are checked in this disassembled code. If they don't work then the bomb explodes. I've worked through it and came up wit a few rules for the numbers but there are parts that I have trouble interpreting. Mainly when it comes to the loops.

Here's the disassembled code for reference:

```
8048eae:       55                      push   %ebp
8048eaf:       89 e5                   mov    %esp,%ebp
8048eb1:       83 ec 28                sub    $0x28,%esp
8048eb4:       c7 45 f8 00 00 00 00    movl   $0x0,0xfffffff8(%ebp)
8048ebb:       8d 45 e4                lea    0xffffffe4(%ebp),%eax
8048ebe:       89 44 24 04             mov    %eax,0x4(%esp)
8048ec2:       8b 45 08                mov    0x8(%ebp),%eax
8048ec5:       89 04 24                mov    %eax,(%esp)
8048ec8:       e8 69 06 00 00          call   8049536 <read_five_numbers>
8048ecd:       8b 45 e4                mov    0xffffffe4(%ebp),%eax
8048ed0:       83 f8 1a                cmp    $0x1a,%eax
8048ed3:       74 05                   je     8048eda <level_3+0x2c>
8048ed5:       e8 a6 10 00 00          call   8049f80 <explode_bomb>
8048eda:       c7 45 fc 00 00 00 00    movl   $0x0,0xfffffffc(%ebp)
8048ee1:       eb 2c                   jmp    8048f0f <level_3+0x61>
8048ee3:       8b 45 fc                mov    0xfffffffc(%ebp),%eax
8048ee6:       8b 54 85 e4             mov    0xffffffe4(%ebp,%eax,4),%edx
8048eea:       8b 45 fc                mov    0xfffffffc(%ebp),%eax
8048eed:       83 c0 01                add    $0x1,%eax
8048ef0:       8b 44 85 e4             mov    0xffffffe4(%ebp,%eax,4),%eax
8048ef4:       39 c2                   cmp    %eax,%edx
8048ef6:       7f 05                   jg     8048efd <level_3+0x4f>
8048ef8:       e8 83 10 00 00          call   8049f80 <explode_bomb>
8048efd:       8b 45 fc                mov    0xfffffffc(%ebp),%eax
8048f00:       8b 44 85 e4             mov    0xffffffe4(%ebp,%eax,4),%eax
8048f04:       0f af 45 fc             imul   0xfffffffc(%ebp),%eax
8048f08:       01 45 f8                add    %eax,0xfffffff8(%ebp)
8048f0b:       83 45 fc 01             addl   $0x1,0xfffffffc(%ebp)
8048f0f:       83 7d fc 03             cmpl   $0x3,0xfffffffc(%ebp)
8048f13:       7e ce                   jle    8048ee3 <level_3+0x35>
8048f15:       8b 45 f4                mov    0xfffffff4(%ebp),%eax
8048f18:       f7 d8                   neg    %eax
8048f1a:       3b 45 f8                cmp    0xfffffff8(%ebp),%eax
8048f1d:       74 05                   je     8048f24 <level_3+0x76>
8048f1f:       e8 5c 10 00 00          call   8049f80 <explode_bomb>
8048f24:       c9                      leave  
8048f25:       c3                      ret
```

So far i have the following rules to find the numbers:

- the first number should be 26 because of the comparison to 0x1a.
- there is a for loop that iterates 4 times and makes sure that each number is less than the number at the current index
  Here are the rules that I'm unsure about
- the sum of the first four numbers should be less than equal to something.
- the last number should be the negative of the first number

Comment: When you say "5 numbers that would work in this code", what does "work" mean, exactly?

Comment: it means if a user provides 5 numbers the bomb shouldn't explode

Comment: @MarceloCantos My objective is to get some input on if i'm interpreting it right. i'm not looking for a solution to it.

Comment: @user1386132: Your objective in the asking the question is obvious. I wanted to know what the expected behaviour was. You should add your explanation to the top of the question.

Comment: @MarceloCantos I edited it. Does it make a bit more sense now?

Comment: So does any one have any ideas on this? I just need some kind of feedback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the beginning of the function, you can view the stack layout as this:

```
int v[5], c0, c1;

ebp+e4 | v1
ebp+e8 | v2
ebp+ec | v3
ebp+f0 | v4
ebp+f4 | v5
ebp+f8 | c0
ebp+fc | c1
```

I've transcribed the code into pseudocode, which should answer your questions. Of course the goto can be converted into a `do/while` loop for readability, once you understand what's going on.

```
8048eae push  %ebp                           
8048eaf mov   %esp,%ebp                      
8048eb1 sub   $0x28,%esp                     

8048eb4 movl  $0x0,0xfffffff8(%ebp)          c0 = 0;
8048ebb lea   0xffffffe4(%ebp),%eax          
8048ebe mov   %eax,0x4(%esp)                 
8048ec2 mov   0x8(%ebp),%eax                 
8048ec5 mov   %eax,(%esp)                    
8048ec8 call  8049536 <read_five_numbers>    read_five_numbers(v);
8048ecd mov   0xffffffe4(%ebp),%eax          eax = v[0];
8048ed0 cmp   $0x1a,%eax                     
8048ed3 je    8048eda <level_3+0x2c>         unless(eax == 0x1A)
                                             {
8048ed5 call  8049f80 <explode_bomb>           explode_bomb();
                                             }
8048eda movl  $0x0,0xfffffffc(%ebp)          c1 = 0;
8048ee1 jmp   8048f0f <level_3+0x61>         goto loop_condition;
                                             loop_body:
8048ee3 mov   0xfffffffc(%ebp),%eax          eax = c1;
8048ee6 mov   0xffffffe4(%ebp,%eax,4),%edx   edx = v[eax];
8048eea mov   0xfffffffc(%ebp),%eax          eax = c1;
8048eed add   $0x1,%eax                      ++eax;
8048ef0 mov   0xffffffe4(%ebp,%eax,4),%eax   eax = v[eax];
8048ef4 cmp   %eax,%edx                      
8048ef6 jg    8048efd <level_3+0x4f>         unless(edx > eax)
                                             {
8048ef8 call  8049f80 <explode_bomb>           explode_bomb();
                                             }
8048efd mov   0xfffffffc(%ebp),%eax          eax = c1;
8048f00 mov   0xffffffe4(%ebp,%eax,4),%eax   eax = v[eax];
8048f04 imul  0xfffffffc(%ebp),%eax          eax *= c1;
8048f08 add   %eax,0xfffffff8(%ebp)          c0 += eax;
8048f0b addl  $0x1,0xfffffffc(%ebp)          ++c1;
                                             loop_condition:
8048f0f cmpl  $0x3,0xfffffffc(%ebp)          if(c1 <= 3) {
8048f13 jle   8048ee3 <level_3+0x35>           goto loop_body;
                                             }
8048f15 mov   0xfffffff4(%ebp),%eax          eax = v[4];
8048f18 neg   %eax                           eax = -eax;
8048f1a cmp   0xfffffff8(%ebp),%eax          
8048f1d je    8048f24 <level_3+0x76>         unless(c0 == eax)
                                             {
8048f1f call  8049f80 <explode_bomb>           explode_bomb();
                                             }
8048f24 leave                                
8048f25 ret
```

So if I'm reading this right, your numbers need to be:

- the first one must equal 0x1A.
- the second must be smaller than the first.
- the third one must be smaller than the second.
- the fourth one must be smaller than the third.
- `(1 * second + 2 * third + 3 * fourth)` must equal the negative of the fifth number.

Comment: turns out that the num1 > num2 > num3 > num4 which means that the number has to be less than the number at the current index. other then this everything else work. Thanks.

Comment: @user1386132: Sorry! I'm used to Intel syntax, so I misinterpreted the meaning of `cmp; jg;`.